# Showing a wait cursor in ActiveX control

Tags: mfc, activex

I am developing an ActiveX control that shows the graph after taking data from the data source. It takes some time for the data to arrive. I want to show a wait cursor in that control.

I am doing something like this

```
m_clsWait = new CWaitCursor(); //this is in constructor

.
.
m_clWait->Restore() // This is in drawing logic.
```

but no matter what I do I don't see the wait cursor.

Is it possible to show wait cursor in ActiveX control?

Comment: Try something like this `{ CWaitCursor x; Sleep(5000); }` cursor will be restored as soon as `x` goes out of scope. But something might happen in the middle, for example another thread changes the cursor.

Comment: I think a better way to do this would be to print a message within the extent of the control in the OnDraw event handler.  Something like "Please wait...Processing".

Comment: I am curious. Why do you still use ActiveX now day?

Comment: @TomTom I am developing an add-in for a legacy app. The ActiveX is to be deployed on special hardware using Windows CE not on PC or laptop. Development however is done on laptop.